# "for that matter"

Tags: sentence-meaning

In this sentence:

> He doesn't like young women or any women for that matter

What's the main "matter", his not liking all kinds of women, or merely young women?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13602/the-exact-meaning-of-for-that-matter

Comment: @Inazuma I see it as slightly different, but the other question and answers can add more info.

Answer (score 1):

Out of context, I would read that to mean that for some reason, the question of his not liking young women (or whether he did) had come up, and the sentence indicates that he does not like them.  Then [it expands on the point](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/for-that-matter), to indicate that he does not like women in general.

However, which is the main matter can not be told from this snippet.  The comment on women in general could just be a digression while the discussion concentrated on young women, or it could shift the discussion to his misogyny.

Answer (score 0):

The main point would actually be that he does not like women, at all.  Without seeing the context around the sentence, the author seems to be using this method of writing to surprise the reader - ultimately letting you know that the man does not like any woman.

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with homosexuality?  The man in question could just as easily be a [misogynist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misogyny).  I don't think new learners of English should get the idea that this necessarily has something to do with sexuality.

Comment: @stangdon Good point.  I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: so what do I have to infer from your answers , the author's intention was to imply that the man doesn't like any women at all or simply youngsters? please be more clear.

Comment: The author would have been responding to the question of whether the man likes young women, and then would have added that he doesn't like any women at all as a *side note*. 

So the first phrase would have been more specific to the situation, but the latter might be important to the construction of his character in later events.

Comment: @CavidHummatov Any women at all, as my post still says